# How to properly run Docker containers and YARN server with WSL 2 in Windows 10?

Tags: docker, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

The question may be poorly formed, but let me explain.

## Initial setup

I had my web-dev Laravel project in `C:\dev\gitlab.our-company.com\laravel-backend` with a Vue app in `.\public\vue-frontend`.

I use Docker (using WSL 2 based engine) with the following commands:

```sh
// First time
export AUTH_TOKEN='glpat-XXX'
export COMPOSER_AUTH='{"http-basic":{"gitlab.our-company.com": {"username": "oauth2", "password": "${AUTH_TOKEN}"}}}'
docker build -f deployment/app.Dockerfile --build-arg COMPOSER_AUTH -t laravel_backend_app .
docker build -f deployment/web.Dockerfile --build-arg AUTH_TOKEN -t laravel_backend_web .
// Always
docker-compose -f deployment/docker-compose.yml -f deployment/docker-compose.override.yml -p laravel_backend up
```

Then I open container's bash with

```sh
docker-compose -f deployment/docker-compose.yml -f deployment/docker-compose.override.yml -p laravel_backend exec app bash
```

which in turn allows me to run `php artisan test`.

I can also run

```sh
yarn --cwd ./public/vue-frontend/ install && yarn --cwd ./public/vue-frontend/ serve
```

to serve the frontend.

## Why I made changes

Running `php artisan test` or `vendor/bin/grumphp run` in container's bash was ridiculously slow (x10).

## Current setup

```sh
$ wsl docker --version
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
```

Using Ubuntu for Windows with `explorer.exe .` I copied entire `C:\dev` to (Ubuntu)~/dev

I rebuilt Docker containers and `up`-ed them, executed `app bash` and tried `php artisan test`. It is now lightning fast.

## Question 1

I can do the procedure in the last paragraph in 2 ways.

1. I can open VS Code integrated terminal in `//wsl$/Ubuntu/home/{USER}/dev/gitlab.our-company.com/laravel-backend` and do the above procedure directly there, or

2. as an extra step, when in terminal, I can execute `wsl` command and my location becomes `~/dev/gitlab.our-company.com/laravel-backend` before continuing with said procedure.

In both cases, I get my `php artisan test` improvement speed.

Which is correct, or for some reason better?

## Problem

I had issues with `yarn`, so in Ubuntu for Windows I installed `nvm` and then with it `nodejs`, `npm`, `yarn`.

Yarn is installed in both cases, thought a tad different version.

```sh
//wsl$/Ubuntu/home/{USER}/dev/gitlab.our-company.com/laravel-backend (205-issue-title)
$ yarn --version
1.22.17
$ wsl
{USER}@DESKTOP-NAME:~/dev/gitlab.our-company.com/laravel-backend$ yarn --version
1.22.15
```

Now the problem is serving the app.

```sh
//wsl$/Ubuntu/home/{USER}/dev/gitlab.our-company.com/laravel-backend (205-issue-title)
$ yarn --cwd ./public/vue-frontend/ install && yarn --cwd ./public/vue-frontend/ serve
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[-/3] ⡀ waiting...
[2/3] ⡀ ejs
error \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\{USER}\dev\gitlab.our-company.com/laravel-backend\public\vue-frontend\node_modules\yorkie: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node bin/install.js
Arguments:
Directory: \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\{USER}\dev\gitlab.our-company.com/laravel-backend\public\vue-frontend\node_modules\yorkie  
Output:
'\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\{USER}\dev\gitlab.our-company.com/laravel-backend\public\vue-frontend\node_modules\yorkie'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\bin\install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

or with `wsl`:

```sh
{USER}@DESKTOP-3OMP0G1:~/dev/gitlab.our-company.com/laravel-backend$ yarn --cwd ./public/vue-frontend/ install && yarn --cwd ./public/vue-frontend/ serve
yarn install v1.22.15
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://gitlab.our-company.com/api/v4/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/@our-company/case-messaging/-/@our-company/case-messaging-1.0.3.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/{USER}/dev/gitlab.our-company.com/laravel-backend/public/vue-frontend/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now believe the second way ie. in `wsl` is the right way.

If anyone has a deeper, better or different explanation I will review it, and likely mark it as the accepted answer.

The problem I had with running `yarn install` in `wsl` is somewhat unrelated to the question and was caused by an NPM package that resides in Our Company's self hosted GitLab (as opposed to NPM public registry) and `npm` had no access to download the `case-messaging` package.

Solved it with

```
npm config set @our-company:registry https://gitlab.our-company.com/api/v4/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/
npm config set -- '//gitlab.our-company.com/api/v4/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken' "${AUTH_TOKEN}"
```